# Какой класс JDK 1.8 используется для отображения размеченного комментария Java?

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, sublime-text, javadoc

**[Формат комментариев](https://codeshare.io/VpSSP)** типа: `/** Текст */` является JavaDoc (некой HTML) документацией, которая помогает анализировать код, но как? Возможно даже **[и иные форматы](https://codeshare.io/AyZUD)** - могут быть размечены как HTML (предполагаю подобно части `<body>`), так ли это?

Какими методами можно отобразить эти комментарии после компиляции? (ну или как часть упомянутой)

Comment: @Vartlok , Перефразировал, так читабельно?

Comment: Комментарии вида /** */ называются JavaDocs. Они как и все остальные комментарии не попадают в class файлы. Что бы их увидеть нужен исходный код.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Было такое предположение. В каких обстоятельствах, при помощи чего и где отображаются эти комменты? Прочёл, что это помогает анализировать структуру программы, но как? (если раздражаю чрезмерной любопытностью, великодушно приношу глубочайшие извинения, рассчитываю @Vartlok на твою филантропичность)

Comment: JavaDocs используются для описание методов-классов, чтобы было понятно что они вообще делают и для чего предназначены. Своего рода документация.

Comment: Из JavaDoc комментариев с помощью инструментов можно сгенерировать документацию.